# Difference between local MSP and Channel MSP?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i have been reading the docs of `hyperledger` fabric but i have been stuck on something. what does this paragraph actually mean:

"The split between channel and local `MSPs` reflects the needs of organizations to administer their local resources, such as a peer or orderer nodes, and their channel resources, such as ledgers, smart contracts, and consortia, which operate at the channel or network level.

It’s helpful to think of these `MSPs` as being at different levels, with `MSPs` at a higher level relating to network administration concerns while `MSPs` at a lower level handle identity for the administration of private resources. `MSPs` are mandatory at every level of administration — they must be defined for the network, channel, peer, orderer, and users."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSP is both a module in Fabric's nodes (peers and orderers) that validates identities and classifies them to principals, and also an instance of such a module.

So, you can have multiple MSPs in each peer/orderer and they all belong to some channel, or they just belong to the node itself.

Every instance of an MSP is used by Fabric policies and access control code to define who can do what.
The Fabric policy infrastructure, and all access control code, either directly or indirectly use MSPs.

So, if the node uses an access control check, or a policy evaluation in the context of some channel, it uses some MSP in that channel.

If it uses an access control check (or a policy evaluation) that is not related to any channel, it uses the local MSP.

Examples of when channel MSPs are used is - when a peer commits a block, it checks the endorsement policy of the transactions of chaincodes. The endorsement policy is fetched from the world state (which resides in the database) and then the policy string is converted to a policy instance, which uses a channel "MSP manager" which contains all MSPs defined for that channel. Every such MSP - belongs to some organization in the channel.

An Example of when the local MSP is used, is - when you install a chaincode on a peer - the operation is not in the context of any channel, so - the local MSP checks that the gRPC call comes with a signature that is signed by some peer administrator, and the definition of who is the admin is defined in the local MSP.