# Hyperledger Fabric: MSPDir in configtx.yaml vs ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

The [configtx.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/balance-transfer/artifacts/channel/configtx.yaml) allows one to set a MSPDir. example below:

```
Organizations:

  - &ord

    Name: ord

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: ordMSP

    # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
    MSPDir: /data/orgs/ord/msp
```

but when starting an orderer or peer one can also define the environment variable ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR as is done e.g. [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/fabric-ca/scripts/env.sh#L166).

Aren't these two ways to set the same thing? Which one trumps over the other? Say the MSPDir in yaml file is set to A whereas ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR is set to B, what is going to happen in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer to this question is that ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR is defining the local MSP whereas the configtx.yaml is defining the channel MSP. 
The ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR in orderer.yaml contains the identity of the orderer. `configtx.yaml` contains MSP directories for all the participants in 
the network. These identities are stored in the [genesis block](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/glossary.html) and from there on anyone submitting transactions can have their identity verified and authenticated as mentioned [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html).

> Secondly, we point to the location of the MSP directory for each
>   member, in turn allowing us to store the root certificates for each
>   Org in the orderer genesis block. This is a critical concept. Now any
>   network entity communicating with the ordering service can have its
>   digital signature verified.

[Difference between local MSP and Channel MSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52494387/difference-between-local-msp-and-channel-msp)

Answer (score 0):

The environments variables [override](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/commands/peernode.html#start-description) the properties in the config file (in this case orderer.yaml, and the peer case, core.yaml). You can see in the [docker-compose](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/first-network/base/docker-compose-base.yaml) file an example of how it works, inside the container has set the FABRIC_CFG_PATH  to the orderer.yaml directory but the environment variables override the configuration file.